# Pdfmake server side Firebase function

Tags: firebase, pdf, google-cloud-functions, server-side, pdfmake

Hi I'm trying to implement pdfmake in firebase cloud function, I have followed this guide https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/getting-started/server-side/
And this is my code:

```
const fonts = {
  Dosis: {
    normal: 'fonts/a.ttf',
    bold: 'fonts/a.ttf',
    italics: 'fonts/a.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'fonts/a.ttf',
  }
};

const printer = new Printer(fonts);
var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(myPdfStructure);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('document.pdf'))
pdfDoc.end()
```

this is my function folder inside my project

[image: folder]

The problem is that I always get this error:

```
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fonts/a.ttf'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at Function.open (/srv/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:3236:16)
at PDFDocument.font (/srv/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:3306:33)
at FontProvider.provideFont (/srv/node_modules/pdfmake/src/fontProvider.js:62:58)
at /srv/node_modules/pdfmake/src/textTools.js:319:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at measure (/srv/node_modules/pdfmake/src/textTools.js:298:13)
at TextTools.buildInlines (/srv/node_modules/pdfmake/src/textTools.js:32:17)
at DocMeasure.measureLeaf (/srv/node_modules/pdfmake/src/docMeasure.js:235:28)
```

Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Try `lib/fonts/a.ttf` instead of `fonts/a.ttf` since relative paths are probably from the `package.json` functions root and not the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving your fonts folder as an immediate child of functions.  Typically, for a TypeScript setup, lib **only** contains generated JS files, and nothing else.  This lets you leave the entire folder out of source control, since you can easily rebuild it all.

With fonts under functions, you should be able to reference them as "./fonts/a.ttf".